# How to: Android Camera App saves image to internal storage

Tags: android, android-camera, internal-storage

I currently am using codes from this http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-working-with-camera-api/. Now, I want to change the code that instead of saving the images to the external storage, i want it to be saved to the internal storage. I dont know which codes to change so that there aren't any redundant codes. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You cannot save the the pictures from camera into internal storage because when you launch the camera using the code from androidhive, the camera is considered as third party application and a third party application cannot access the internal storage. You have the original answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32118662/save-the-photos-from-camera-to-android-internal-storage)