# save the photos from camera to android internal storage

Tags: android, android-camera

I successfully save the pictures from android camera
to using the following root paths

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

and

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
```

but I cannot save using the following root path

```
context.getFilesDir()
```

Do you know if it is possible to save the pictures taken from android camera to the android internal storage which have `context.getFilesDir()` as root folder?

I use the following code to start the camera:

```
    Intent takePictureIntent = new  
             Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(picFile));
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE);

//and this code I used to get the camera output


 @Override
           public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,
            Intent data) {
        if ((requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE) && (resultCode ==
            Activity.RESULT_OK)
                ) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Can get the image.",   
             Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");     

          //  System.out.println("photo "+photo.getWidth());
//          final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);            
//            imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);        
            } else if ((requestCode == REQUEST_TAKE_PICTURE) && (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED)) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Cannot get the image.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } 

        }
```

Comment: How are you taking the pictures? Are you using `android.hardware.Camera`? Are you using `android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager`? Are you using `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE`? Are you using something else?

Comment: I added to the question description the code that I am using to take photos from camera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `getFilesDir()`, because you are launching a third-party camera app to take the picture, and it cannot write to your app's internal storage.

Comment: can I update somehow the code for starting camera in order to not consider the camera as third party application?

Comment: @roshca181: You are welcome to use `android.hardware.Camera` or `android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager` to more directly interface with camera hardware and take pictures yourself. This is a lot more complicated to do. You might consider taking the picture using your existing code, having the image be written to external storage initially, then simply moving the file to internal storage when the picture is taken.